C# string length validation for SQL Server UTF-8 collation columns
I'm struggling with communicating length validation issues in my C# app to business users for string values that are stored in SQL Server using columns with UTF-8 collation (Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8).
For example: a Product class with a Name property with a maximum length of 255 characters.
Products are stored in the Product table with a Name column with datatype varchar(255) expressing 255 bytes.
When the user enters a Name of exactly 255 characters, validating the length of the string in C# will succeed.
When all characters in the Name are in the UTF-8 1 byte code range, there is no problem with the database as well. However if there is only one character in the 2 bytes or more code range, SQL Server will throw an exception:

String or binary data would be truncated

I think it is not an option to ask the business user to go find and correct the more than 1 byte character. So what are ways to solve this use case?

Use a factor for the number of bytes in the database. E.g. assume (most) characters are 1-2 bytes, so for a string with a maximum of 255 characters use a 510 bytes varchar column.

Pros: (1) Saves space considering most characters are in the 1 byte code range.
Cons: (1) Unfortunately some common characters like monetary units (Euro-sign, etc.) are in the 3 bytes range, so this might cause the same problem again.
(2) Difference between string length and column length might be harder to maintain and understand.


Use nvarchar in the database.

Pros:
(1) 2 bytes for the 3 bytes code range.
(2) string length and column length are equal.
Cons:
(1) Considering most characters are in the 1 byte code range, a more expensive solution.


Using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes().Length the storage issue can be discovered in C# already.
Pros:
(1) Take advantage of UTF-8 storage.
(2) Doesn't require hacky solutions like option 1.
(3) Doesn't require a database roundtrip.
Cons:
(1) How to explain the user how to solve the issue.
(2) Get the length in bytes is a more expensive call.


Any thoughts?

Use nvarchar in the database - space is cheap, and if some characters could be multiple byte then this is the correct datatype to use. I would suggest you should almost always use nvarchar unless you know for a fact your data is very plain and very boring. Just consider the complexity of the other solutions you are considering just to save a few bytes of storage... seriously don't do it.

Also if you turn on ROW or PAGE compression for a table, SQL Server uses Unicode Compression for the nvarchar(n) and nchar(n) columns. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-ver16

Your nvarchar assumptions are only valid for UCS-2 encoding and/or the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. If you need to include Unicode Supplementary Multilingual Plane code points then you need to be using UTF-16 encoding instead and you're back in the situation where composed characters could occupy 2 or 4 bytes.

What's your plan for indicating non-ASCII characters in the UI? Are you highlighting them in some way? (e.g.: background colour, bolding, italicizing, underlines or squiggles?) You can still do that with method 3 where you're recomputing the encoded UTF-8 length with each change in the edited value.

@AlwaysLearning thanks for your reply. True that supplementary characters would require 4 bytes. However I'm expecting to encounter this far less than characters in the UTF-8 1-3 byte range.
It really depends on the use for a column. For webpages the page title, content, etc. can contain emoji which are in the 4 bytes range. Thought content is usually `(n)varchar(max). I will try some different setups to see how users responds to feedback when they exceed the number of bytes instead of characters.

@DaleK, thanks! I'm going to take your advice.

Isn't nvarchar bad to use with utf8 collations? I think the real solution would be just to use long enough strings. perhaps even nvarchar(max) for descriptions etc. For stuff like product name, even 100 characters sounds ridiculously long to me so how big can the problem be in reality. Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes().Length sounds like a decent compromise if you want to be nice to the user, and if you're worrying about expensive calls when user enters text, think about how often it happens, it's no problem at all

@siggemannen, I'm not aware of UTF-8 collation problems with nvarchar. I will look into this to be sure. Though I can of course change to Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC as well.
I agree 100 chars sounds long. I'm usually using 255 or max for storage. The 100 chars is considered validation rule. This allows us to be flexible between validation and storage.
The difficult thing, imo, using bytes length for feedback to a user is that they need to understand the "weight" of chars. The user can count chars, but validation on char weight adds an extra dimension which might be hard to understand.

What you can do is to display some sort of marker near the text box that automatically added/removed based on the length, this way there will be feedback to max length. No need to get into details of unicodes. But yes, if the user is close to hitting the max length during normal operations, it means that the lengths are far too short. Let's say you wanna limit to 100 chars, then the varchar string should be 4 x 100, which would cover even the worst unicode offenders

@siggemannen, Alternatively, starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x), if a UTF-8 enabled collation (_UTF8) is used, previously non-Unicode data types (char and varchar) become Unicode data types using UTF-8 encoding. SQL Server 2019 (15.x) doesn't change the behavior of previously existing Unicode data types (nchar, nvarchar, and ntext), which continue to use UCS-2 or UTF-16 encoding. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#unicode-data-types

I guess set the limit in the UI to half as much as the max length in the database should cover you. nvarchar won't always help either: eg what about smileys.

@Charlieface voor nvarchar this would help. smileys require 4 bytes, where nvarchar uses 2 bytes by default. For varchar in UTF-8 it is more complicated, as a character can be 1-4 bytes. E.g. the Euro-sign is 3 bytes. So would have to pick 4 times the storage there as well.
